# Swift. Want an if statement that will give an error if value is not an integer

Tags: swift2

I am new to this an am trying to learn as much as I can. I have a variable that has a numerical value, I want an if statement that will look at this value and give an err if this value is not an integer. Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of your variable?  If it is a `Double`, then `if value != floor(value) {
    print("error")
}` should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it like this and then work with `number` inside the if clause:

```
if let number = numericalValue as? Int {
   // numericalValue is an Int
} else {
   // numericalValue is not an Int 
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will test this.

Answer (score 0):

I use Int() coupled with an if statement to achieve this:

```
//var number = 17  - will print "17 is an integer"
//var number = "abc"  - will print "Error"

if let numberTest = Int(number) {
    print("\(number) is an integer")
} else {
    print("Error")
}
```

Comment: This does not even compile, because `Int(number)'  does not return an Optional.

Comment: I tested it in playground and got the results I commented out. Do you know why it is allowed there?

Comment: I don't know, but another problem with this approach is that it would also print "1.2 is an integer".

Comment: Ah, excellent point. I didn't even consider that. I'm going to do some testing on this in playground and see if I can figure out why it's not giving me any errors there.

Comment: I managed to solve it in the end. I found the remainder operator in the Swift manual. Thought if I used that, divided by 1, if there was a remainder then the original value couldn't be an integer. So my code was - else if ((Double(guessEnteredNumber.text!)!) % 1 ) > 0
        {
            resultText.text = "You need to guess a whole number between 1 and 5"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it in the end. I found the remainder operator in the Swift manual. Thought if I used that, divided by 1, if there was a remainder then the original value couldn't be an integer. So my code was - else if ((Double(guessEnteredNumber.text!)!) % 1 ) > 0 { resultText.text = "You need to guess a whole number between 1 and 5"

Answer (score 0):

In swift 2 you can now use the 'guard' keyword like this

```
guard let number = myNumber as Int else {
    // myNumber is not an Int
    return
}
// myNumber is an Int and you can use number as it is not null
```

You can replace the 'let' keyword by a 'var' if you need to modify 'number' afterward